# Which Python packages are installed on Mavericks?

Tags: macos, python

The title says it all: How can I find out which Python packages are pre-installed with Mavericks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739993/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-locally-installed-python-modules) you just can type

```
python -c "help('modules')"
```

or

```
pip freeze
```

Comment: pip is not party of the Apple install

Comment: thats why I wrote "or". If he had installed pip for any reason, he could look it up with that command.